# Error SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor when using @ModelAttribute in Spring project

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-boot, modelattribute

I am trying to update username using form. Problem is that when I am using @ModelAttribute I am getting below error:

> Error during execution of processor
>   'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor'
>   (account:79)

**Full error information from IDE:**

> 2017-12-30 09:03:16.082 ERROR 6536 --- [nio-8080-exec-7]
>   o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for
>   servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
>   [Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during
>   execution of processor
>   'org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor'
>   (account:79)] with root cause
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain
>   target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.(BindStatus.java:144)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:401)
>   ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:328)
>   ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:294)
>   ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.processor.attr.AbstractSpringFieldAttrProcessor.processAttribute(AbstractSpringFieldAttrProcessor.java:98)
>   ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.processor.attr.AbstractAttrProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttrProcessor.java:87)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.processor.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:212)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.applyNextProcessor(Node.java:1017)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:972)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.computeNextChild(NestableNode.java:695)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.NestableNode.doAdditionalProcess(NestableNode.java:668)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Node.processNode(Node.java:990)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.dom.Document.process(Document.java:93)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1155)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011)
>   ~[thymeleaf-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:335)
>   ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:190)
>   ~[thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar:2.1.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1286)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1041)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]    at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
>   ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
>   ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   [na:1.8.0_152]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   [na:1.8.0_152]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_152]

**Account Controller class:**

```
@Controller
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("/account")
    public ModelAndView adminPage(){
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("account");
        //modelAndView.addObject("users", userService.getAllUsers());
        return modelAndView;
    }


    @PutMapping("/renameUsername")
    public ModelAndView renameUserName(@ModelAttribute("user") User newUserName) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String currentUser = auth.getName();
        userService.changeUsername(currentUser, newUserName);
        return new ModelAndView("account");
    }
```

**Model User class:**

```
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class User {
    @Id
    private String logonName;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String password;
    private String recoveryQuestion;
    @JsonIgnore
    private String recoveryAnswer;

}
```

**User service method responsible for username change:**

```
public  void changeUsername(String oldUserName, User newUserName) {
    User user = userRepository.findOne(oldUserName);
    user.setLogonName(newUserName.getLogonName());
    userRepository.save(user);
}
```

**account.html code snippet:**

```html
<div class="jumbotron">
  <form th:action="@{/renameUsername}" th:method="put" th:object="${user}">
    <dl class="row">
      <dt class="col-sm-5">
<p>Change username:</p>
<p class="description">Enter your username, which you will use to login</p>
</dt>
      <dd class="col-sm-7">
        <p>
          <label for="inputUser" class="sr-only">username</label>
          <input type="text" id="inputUser" class="form-control" name="logonName" th:field="*{logonName}" placeholder="Username" />
        </p>
        <p>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Update username</button>a
        </p>
      </dd>
    </dl>
  </form>
</div>
```

I have tried to fix the problem using articles in which people where reporting similar problems but solutions where not working. Mostly there was problems with typo in variable/model name. I checked this but still I am getting this problem.

Any suggestions why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code `/modelAndView.addObject("users", userService.getAllUsers());`
.
But in your view `<form th:action="@{/renameUsername}" th:method="put" th:object="${user}">`:

Changes `users` to `user`.

Comment: As you can see in my example modelAndView line is commented as I try also to iterate through list of users but same error was there.

Comment: @ aristotll you have pointed me in right direction when i uncommented addObject line and changed if to:`modelAndView.addObject("user", userService.findUserByLogin(currentUser));` I'm no longer getting _SpringInputGeneralFieldAttrProcessor_. RIght now I'm getting: _identifier of an instance of com.code.model.User was altered from admin to erni; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: identifier of an instance of com.code..model.User was altered from admin to erni_